# Installing Wordpress in another location to my wordpress customisations

Tags: php, svn, wordpress

I'd like to install wordpress in another directory to the actual DocumentRoot so that I can keep it under version control but at the same time customise my wordpress site.

So I have a directory layout something like this

```
branches/
tags/
trunk/
  index.php
  wp-content/ < this is where I will have my customisations
vendors/
  wordpress/ < this is svn co from wordpress repo
```

I may have set it out incorrectly above, but I hope you get the idea of what I want to achieve. I only want to store my customisations my repo and have the core WP stuff co from their repo.

Answer (score 1):

Use symbolic links if you're using a *nix system and set the DocumentRoot to "trunk".
eg. `ln -s path/to/vendors/wordpress/wp-admin path/to/trunk/`